# Is there a way to have a generated nuxt app and only change the .env file in the server without having to regenerate the code?

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

The request is to edit the .env and the generated nuxt app to catch the changes, to have different variables for different servers, is that doable somehow?

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't get more up votes, currently there is no good way to change the environment variables for a spa or static site...

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no way to change .env file without regenerating code

Therefor most developer use Docker to solve this problem:

https://jonathanmh.com/deploying-a-nuxt-js-app-with-docker/

Comment: So, every time something changes we need to stop and run the docker container again right?

Comment: You can change it in runtime, please check this link 

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#docker-runtime-execution-options